# Calculate the curve of a list and apply that to calculate the values of a larger list

Tags: python, r, prediction, forecasting, data-analysis

I have a list of ~125 sorted ascending values and I am converting those to percentages of total so that they add up to 100% (shortened example would be: 0%, 0%, 15%, 15%, 30%, 40% with the total of those 100%). I'm trying to calculate the curve associated with that list and apply it to a larger list so that I have a list of say 300 values (or any number I choose) that total 100% but have that same exact curve/distribution as the first list (if you charted both of these lists they would show the same exact trend/pattern. Basically I'm using this to forecast the large list values based on what the trend shown in the small list.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the curve associated with that list", "same exact curve/distribution as the first list (if you charted both of these lists they would show the same exact trend/pattern"?  Can you give an example longer list for your 6-element list?